# Submit button doesn't send me an email ,just send me to another page

Tags: php, header, submit-button

```
//email body
$message_body =  "Message from $sender_name\n";
$message_body .=  "------------------------------\n";
$message_body .=  "$message\n";
$message_body .=  "------------------------------\n";
$message_body .=  "$sender_name\n";
$message_body .=  "$sender_email\n";
$message_body .=  "$country_code$phone_number\n";

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = 'From: '. $sender_name .'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$sender_email.'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
header('Location: payment.php');
}
?>
```

when I click submit button, it sends me to the payment page, but it doesn't send me an email, why?

Comment: hi remove the header and debug the `$send_mail` and see what you are getting

Comment: Make sure your email SMTP server is working, and try to make script containing only `mail()` line (with parameters of course) and what happens then?

Comment: Try terminating message_body with \r\n.  Check if $send_mail is true or false.

Comment: i want it to  send me an email and send me to payment page